# Error in when connecting to the wifi in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want to connect wifi in xamarin ios and getting this error:

> Error Domain=NEHotspotConfigurationErrorDomain Code=8 "internal
>   error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=internal error.}

```
var wifiManager = new NEHotspotConfigurationManager();
            var wifiConfig = new NEHotspotConfiguration(ssid, password, false);
            wifiConfig.JoinOnce = false;
            wifiManager.RemoveConfiguration(ssid);
            wifiManager.ApplyConfigurationAsync(wifiConfig);
            wifiManager.ApplyConfiguration(wifiConfig, (error) =>
            {
               if (error != null)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(error.GetType());
                  Console.WriteLine($"Error while connecting to WiFi network {ssid}: {error.LocalizedDescription}");
                 Console.WriteLine($"Error while connecting to WiFi network {ssid}: {error.Description}");

                           }
                      });

}
```

Comment: Add the HotSpot Capability to the AppID you are using, also add it in Entitlements.plist ->Hotspot Configuration ->check  `enable Hotspot Configuration`

Comment: both the option is enabled.

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: I think the problem is not with the code i have try many codes but the problem is same in all codes.

Comment: code is attached with question.

Comment: Refer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/141409/problem-with-hotspotconfiguration-and-entitlement

Comment: i have tried all these things but the problem is same.

Comment: Delete the  folder bin and obj , then clean and rebuild your project .